# Android - TranslateAnimation update dynamically the size of the Layout

Tags: java, android, animation, android-framelayout, translate-animation

I'm trying to do an animation that goes like this:

**The context:**

I have two `EditText`'s I need that when you click over one, the another one come out from behind the first one. Here you have some pictures to get a image of what I want.
[image: Application in standby]
[image: Application after you click the first EditText]

To do this obviously I need a `TranslateAnimation` in order to move the second `EditText` from behind the first one.

**My approach:**

The first thing that I could thought was in use a `FrameLayout` put the `EditText` one over another, and then in the onTouch event of the first one do a `TranslateAnimation` on the second one. The problem with this is that if I have the `FrameLayout` height in `wrap_content` then the animation will be invisible to the user. And if I change on runtime the height of the `FrameLayout` I will leave a void below the first `EditText` as you can see in this picture:

[image]

The second solution that I thought was add one `AnimationListener` to the `TranslateAnimation` and in the `onAnimationStart` method change the height of the `FrameLayout`. But the problem with this is that the height of the `FrameLayout` changes too abruptly. I want keep the animation smooth.

**My question:**

How can I get a smooth animation of the second `EditText` from behind the first one, changing the height of the `FrameLayout` as the second `EditText` moves down?

Thanks!

**Update:**

I changed the `FrameLayout` by a `RelativeLayout` I searched and there's no difference for this case. I tried scale this `RelativeLayout` that contains both of the `EditText` with an `AnimationScale` in order to display the animation smoothly, but didn't work. Here is my code:

```
    protected void expanse() {
        Log.d("Accordion", "expandAccordion");
        //Translate the top of the second EditText to its bottom
        TranslateAnimation translateSecond = new TranslateAnimation(second.getLeft(), second.getLeft(), 
                second.getTop(), second.getBottom());
        translateSecond.setDuration(1000);
        //Scale the relative layout to show the both of them
        ScaleAnimation scaleContainer = new ScaleAnimation(container.getLeft(),  container.getLeft(), 
                container.getTop(), second.getBottom());
        scaleContainer.setDuration(1000);
        //At the end of the scaling, change the height of the relative layout
        scaleContainer.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListenerAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) container.getLayoutParams();
                params.height = second.getBottom();
                container.setLayoutParams(params);
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            }

        });
        container.startAnimation(scaleContainer);
        second.startAnimation(translateSecond);
    }
```

BTW I can guarantee that if I hardcode some large height like 350dp, the animation is displayed correctly.

**UPDATE:**

I tried moving both, the second `EditText` and the layout below. This is the code. BTW for another reasons I changed the `ListView` by a custom `ViewPager`, this doesn't change anything.

```
  public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private EditText first;
    private EditText second;
    private HoboViewPager pager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pager = (HoboViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setPageTransformer(true, new RotationPageTransformer());
        pager.setAdapter(new SampleAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager()));

        first = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.location_search_field);
        second = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.term_search_field);
        first.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                expanseSecondField();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    protected void expanseSecondField() {
        TranslateAnimation translateSecondField = new TranslateAnimation(second.getLeft(), second.getLeft(), 
                second.getTop(), second.getBottom());
        translateSecondField.setFillAfter(true);
        translateSecondField.setDuration(1000);
                    TranslateAnimation translateContainer = new TranslateAnimation(pager.getLeft(), pager.getLeft(), 
                pager.getTop(), pager.getTop() + second.getBottom());
        translateContainer.setFillAfter(true);
        translateContainer.setDuration(1000);
                    pager.startAnimation(translateContainer);
        second.startAnimation(translateSecondField);
    }
}
```

This didn't work because the TranslateAnimation of the container is executed immediately. The result is the same that when I was trying to change the size of the container at the end of the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How use the 2nd option & try performing two translate animations in tandem: 1 on the EditText, then one on the FrameLayout? Give them both the same exact deltas and duration. This way, the FrameLayout will move down smoothly, then at the end of the animation, change the height of the FrameLayout.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Nice way of think it. I'll give it a try, and if  works I will accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I think that this solution doesn't work because when I perform the animation in the `FrameLayout` the view gets invalidated and I can't see the animation of the `EditText`.Check my update.

Comment: you need to create 2 separate TranslateAnimation instances - are you doing that?

Comment: TranslateAnimation for the EditText and one ScaleAnimation for the container (RelativeLayout now). I didn't get how a TranslateAnimation was going to help me in order to resize the container.

Comment: don't do a ScaleAnimation - that will make the container look like it's squeezing. From what I understood, the container at the bottom extends to the full height of the screen. If this is the case, the TranslateAnimation will push it down, and since the user doesn't see the beneath the bottom of the screen, it will seem like the height is getting smaller.

Comment: Also, im assuming that all the content under the EditTexts is inside another layout which you are animating. This won't work if the EditTexts are inside the same layout you're animating. If this is the case, try putting all the layouts under the EditTexts inside a separate layout and animate that layout.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm giving up with this. I tried what you said, check it in my update. But this seems by far, imposible. I checked all the resources, and there's no single `View` that does what I'm trying to do. Even the `ExpandableListView` the only thing that does is hide/show their childrens. It's really annoying how such simple things like this or display `.gif` images are impossible in android :@